# Unable to send email through Office 365 server?

Tags: vb.net, email, office365

Recently our organization moved from an in house email system to Microsoft Office 365.  I have several applications written in vb.net that send emails after a form has been completed.
The emails work when using our in house server but not the Office365.
I have tried ports 587, 465 and even 25.
Our central IT department is telling me that I need to specify TLS in my code.
But they don't code in .NET at all.

Below is my code.  And below that is the error.

Public Sub send_exchange()

```
    Dim smtp = New SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com")

    With smtp
        .DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        .Port = Convert.ToInt32("587") - have also tried without the TOInt32
        .UseDefaultCredentials = False
        .EnableSsl = True
        .Credentials  = New NetworkCredential("<userID>@uwo.ca","<password>")
        .Timeout = 300000
    End With


    Dim myMail As New MailMessage
    With myMail
        .From = New MailAddress("webedu1@uwo.ca", "Western Education - Client Support")
        .To.Add(New MailAddress("jbentley@uwo.ca", "Julian Bentley"))
        .Subject = "Subject of email"
        .Body = "THis is the body"
    End With

    'Response.Write("<br>Response.End at line 397 is active")
    'Response.End

    Try
        smtp.Send(myMail)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("<br><font color=red>ERROR<br />" & ex.toString & "</font>")
    End Try

End Sub
```

ERROR
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 40.97.92.242:587 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at intranet_intranetSub.send_exchange() in I:\Dev\www.edu.uwo.ca\intranet\intranetSub.master.vb:line 397

Comment: UPDATE - My issue was "resolved".  I was working in our DEV environment which is on a private IP.  So it worked when using our mail server but not when using the external mail server.  Once I moved the application to an outwardly facing system it worked just fine.